# Qualcomm AR Camera overlay view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am using NinevehGL framework and Qualcomm AR  in order to intract with 3D object , but I faced with a problem which is I can not overlay any view , button , text on the camera !!! or better to say add any view to subview !!

for example [self.view addSubView:myImage];

but when camera starts , nothing adds !

I would be grateful if you tell me how to do so ..

Comment: I used the first sample of the Qualcomm AR toolkit, and to add a visible subview, I only had to add it to the ARParentView (which is not the GL view). There has to be something similar in this sample, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your views are positioned correctly (center, bounds, and transform). It's a bit tricky because the AR camera is always displayed in landscape right orientation if you're using the default orientation.

You can display it in portrait orientation, but then you need to modify the values while configuring video background. I suggest to use the default landscape right orientation.